# Как программно разархивировать zip архив?

Tags: delphi, zip

Как можно разархивировать zip-архив (с какой нибудь библиотекой или вообще скриптом) в определенную папку ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, уже нашел самый простой вариант:
использовав `7z.dll` и библиотеку - [Ссылка](http://www.progdigy.com/files/sevenzip.zip)

И сам код для примера:

```
uses SevenZip;

var
  I : Integer;
begin
  // Получаем список файлов
  with CreateInArchive(CLSID_CFormatZip) do
    begin
      OpenFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'file.zip');
      MLog.Lines.Append('Список Файлов:');
      for I := 0 to NumberOfItems - 1 do
        if not ItemIsFolder[I] then
          MLog.Lines.Append(ItemPath[I]);
    end;
  // Распаковывает файлы 
  with CreateInArchive(CLSID_CFormatZip) do
   begin
     OpenFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'file.zip');
     ExtractTo(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'file');
     MLog.Lines.Append('Архив распакован!');
   end;
end;
```

Comment: не в обиду будет сказано, но тогда уж сначала можно было полукморить, а потом уж вопрос задавать

Comment: Извиняюсь, просто долго не мог найти оптимальный вариант,
ZipForge - платный
еще несколько библиотек уж очень медленные.

Answer (score 5):

Замечу, что ZipForge - коммерческий компонент и лицензия обойдется в € 49.

В то же самое время есть свободная [Abbrevia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/) с аналогичным набором фич по лицензии MPL.

Comment: плюсану. не слышал про него. скачаем, посмотрим.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону компонента ZipForge.
Он очень прост в использовании и в интернетах полно информации о нем.

Answer (score 0):

Нужен 7z.exe (7zip - бесплатный архиватор), архиватор положи рядом с исходником программы.

Пишешь процедуру примерно такую:

```
procedure ExtractTo(AArchive, ADestPath: String);
var
  Cmd, Params: String;
begin
  Params:= Format('e -y "%s" -o"%s"', [AArchive, ADestPath]);
  Cmd:= '"' + FArcPath + '7z.exe"';
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Cmd + ' ' + Params));
  ShellExecuteWait(Cmd, Params);
end;

function ShellExecuteWait(AppName, Params: String; WaitTime: Cardinal = INFINITE; ShowMode: Integer = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED): integer;
var
  ShellInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ExitCode: Cardinal;
begin
  Screen.Cursor:= crAppStart;
  try
    with ShellInfo do
    begin
      cbSize:= SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
      fMask:= SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
      Wnd:= HWND_DESKTOP;
      lpVerb:= 'open';
      lpFile:= PAnsiChar(AppName);
      lpParameters:= PAnsiChar(Params);
      lpDirectory:= nil;
      nShow:= ShowMode;
    end;

    if not ShellExecuteEx(@ShellInfo) then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    if ShellInfo.hProcess <> 0 then
      try
        WaitForSingleObject(ShellInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeProcess(ShellInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
        Result:= ExitCode;
      finally
        CloseHandle(ShellInfo.hProcess);
      end
    else
      Result:= -1;
    Application.BringToFront;
    //SetForegroundWindow(Application.MainForm.Handle);
  finally
    Screen.Cursor:= crDefault;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: зачем в данном случае пользоваться посторонними приложениями?  
1. общий размер приложения от этого не уменьшится  
2. скорость работы, отнюдь, не увеличится
3. код выглядит сложнее и больше. Человек, не знакомый с WinApi, не разберется в том, что тут написано. А просто копипастить быдлокод в свой проект - не к добру.

Comment: @an_vital, ну очень удобный способ )

Comment: @Nofate, ты забыл про ![тэг][1]   =)

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/NiCp6.jpg

Comment: Нет всё таки мой способ легче, просто использовав 7z.dll

Comment: То есть 7z.dll - это не стороннее приложение? :)

Comment: @teanЫЧ, а по вашему сторонние компоненты типа ZipForge справятся с ситуацией лучше?

Comment: @an_vital, у всех методов свои плюсы и минусы. очевидные минусы вашего я изложил. И в каком смысле "лучше"? "Лучше" - понятие растяжимое. Если взять те три пункта, которые я описал, и прибавить к ним скорость работы, то ваш метод проигрывает уже по 3/4. По поводу производительности я не в курсе, не сравнивал.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, а вы уже измерили скорость работы? или только на словах предполагаете? и ресурсы уже посчитали сколько кушает библиотека и исполняемый файл? Ждем цифирок :)

Comment: @an_vital, пришлось удалить один комментарий, так как лимит не дремлет.  
> а вы уже измерили скорость работы?  
> По поводу производительности я не в курсе, не сравнивал.  
 
> ресурсы уже посчитали  
Даже если предположить, что исполняемый файл и dll имеют одинаковый набор методов для работы с архивами, то у исполняемого файла есть еще интерфейс, у которого свои методы и свойства, которые также сидят в памяти, даже если вы их не отображаете в своем проекте. Да, учитывая данную ситуацию, можно смело сказать, что разница в поедании ресурсов незначительная. Но есть же.